# How to set labels on jointplot, pairplot, heatmap, catplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am drawing graphs using seaborn on python and want to label x axis and y axis.

When I draw only one graph such as barplot, rugplot, histogram, etc, I could just use:

`pyplot.xlabel('x') pyplot.ylabel('y')`

But for graphs like jointplot, pairplot, heatmap, and catplot, outcome is different from what I expected.

Jointplot draws scatterplot inside and histogram outside. So when I use `pyplot.xlabel('x') pyplot.ylabel('y')`, labels are drawn on axes of histogram.

This code draws 4 catplot and using `xlabel, ylabel` only labels the bottom catplot.

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.catplot(x="sex", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",row="day",
            kind="violin", data=tips, split=True)
pyplot.suptitle("tip - catplot", y=1.01)
pyplot.xlabel('x')
pyplot.ylabel('y')
pyplot.show();
```

How can I label the axes of the entire figure? or each of the graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab each axes object by first assigning the return of `catplot` to a variable. The axes are obtained using the `axes` attribute. Then set labels for these axes:

```
g = sns.catplot(x="sex", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",row="day",
            kind="violin", data=tips, split=True)
for ax, lbl in zip(g.axes.flatten(), 'abcd'):
    ax.set_xlabel(f'x axis {lbl}')
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use on pandas.pivot table and pairplot?

Comment: I tried on pandas.pivot table but using ```flatten``` returns ```list' object has no attribute 'flatten'``` and on pairplot, it only labels the top left subgraph

Comment: Your code labels x axis from top catplot to bottom catplot by a b c d but how can I label each x axis by different name?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you "tried on pandas.pivot table". Your question and my response really only applies to seaborn FacetGrids, eg `catplot` and `pairplot`.

Comment: Just replace `'abcd'` in the loop with a list of names you want to get different labels.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208019/discussion-between-dohun-and-busybear).